# Facing Null Value Data using View Model in .Net MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am student developper in Asp.Net MVC 5. And I am facing a null value problem. When I try to insert my form data for my SQL database , ı see Null value to all column in my database area. I did not find a solution about it. What kind of error i am doing on my code? It should be easy error. But i did not find from any source. Could you help me at this issue?

Models:

```
  public partial class Personel
    {
        public int pid { get; set; }
        public string pAd { get; set; }
        public string pSoyad { get; set; }
        public string pTelNo { get; set; }
        public string yonetici { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> dprFk { get; set; }

        public virtual Departman Departman { get; set; }
    }
```

Class for View :

```
 public class viewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Departman>DepartmanInfo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Personel> PersonelInfo { get; set; }

        public Personel Personel { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller and Create method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new viewModel()
            {
                DepartmanInfo = db.Departman.ToList(),
                PersonelInfo = db.Personel.ToList()
            };
            return View("Create", model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="pid,pAd,pSoyad,pTelNo,yonetici,dprFk")]Personel pModel)
        {
            var personel = new Personel();

            personel.pAd = pModel.pAd;
            personel.pSoyad = pModel.pSoyad;
            personel.pTelNo = pModel.pTelNo;
            personel.yonetici = pModel.yonetici;
            personel.dprFk = pModel.dprFk;
            db.Personel.Add(personel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminUI");

        }
```

My Form html page :

```
@model TelefonRehberi.Models.Class.viewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Personel",FormMethod.Post))
{

         <div class="form-group">
             @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Personel.pAd)
             @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Personel.pAd, new { @class = "form-control" })
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Personel.pSoyad)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Personel.pSoyad, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Personel.pTelNo)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Personel.pTelNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Personel.dprFk)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Personel.dprFk, new SelectList(Model.DepartmanInfo, "dprid", "dprAd"), "Departman  Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Personel.yonetici)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Personel.yonetici, new SelectList(Model.PersonelInfo, "pid", "pAd"), "Yönetici Seçiniz ", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

}
```

Comment: At first glance, I see that your view uses `viewModel`, but your POST action method uses `Personel`. Try stripping out `BindAttribute` and use `viewModel` as POST action parameter, then check if `Personel` properties contains values.

Comment: Also, your ViewModel shouldn't contain database models - it should only contain simple types (int, string, etc.) and other view models

Comment: I found my mistake thanks your advice.